# Odd formating issue with one specific page using CSS

Tags: php, css

I'm having an odd error with one of my pages where the bar that should be on the footer is up in the left hand corner and the links area is supposed to be where the footer bar is. All my other pages are not affected it is just this one. Here is a link to the affected page http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/index.php/schedules/details/4 and here is one of what it is supposed to look like formatting wise http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/index.php/FrontSchedules also these two pages referance off the same stylesheet and layout.tpl file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `#footer` div is inside your `#container` div. Move it outside and below your `#container` div and the page will look better.

Also, your `#sidearea` div is inside your `#mainarea` div. Move it outside and above the #mainarea div.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `<div id="footer">` inside of your `<div id="container"> </div>` area on the affected page. Move it down outside of your container div and all will be well.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

See the below image in which i mention your HTML structure please follow this and it might help you to solve your issue.

[image]

```
<div id="footer"></div> code should be in <div id="wrapper"></div>instead of <div id="container"></div>
```

As mention in above image.

Comment: I did that and now im back to where i was before

Comment: what i suggest is damaging your other pages? or some this else is happening.

Comment: It all the pages except for this one 'http://alohavirtual.virtual-aviation.org/index.php/schedules/details/4. Where as before all the pages were wrong except the one listed in the link. so it keeps flip flopping.

Comment: The problem is your Div footer is coming under the container div. So your footer div should always be child of Wrapper div. See my updated answer.

Comment: I keep moving it in my code but each time it reverts back to where it was before.